# I'm using ajax to set up a view of uploaded data, but it works in first item only

Tags: django, ajax

I have to set up the user should be able to view the contact info of customer, For that I'm using ajax. the code is working but the problem is the ajax is only working in the first item, other buttons are not working what is the reason
another issue is when i hit the button again it showing data agin and agin how to control it

how to solve these two issues

views.py

```
def contact_details(request):

property_details = Property.objects.all()
seraializer = PropertySerializer(property_details, many=True)
data = seraializer.data
return JsonResponse(data, safe=False )
```

HTML page(including ajax)

```
{% if accomodations %}  
{% for accomodation in accomodations %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <img src="{{accomodation.images.url}}" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5">
        <div class="caption">
            <h3>{{ accomodation.headline }}</h3>
            <div>
                {{ accomodation.city }}
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ accomodation.location }}
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ accomodation.facilites }}
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ accomodation.rent }}
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ accomodation.owner }}
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ accomodation.id }}
            </div>
            
            <button id="request-btn" name="property_id"  class="btn btn-primary">Contact info:</button>
            </form>
            <div id=response></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
{% endfor %}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">

          $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#request-btn").click(function(){
        
                 $.ajax({
                   url: "{% URL 'contact_details' %}" ,
                   type: "GET",
                   dataType:"json",
                   success: 
             function(result){

              $.each(result, function() {
                  html = "Email:" +this.email + "<br>" +"Mobile:" + this.mobile +"<hr>"
             $("#response").append(html)
            });
        }
    });
    });
}); 


</script>
   {% else %}
    <h1>Not Found</h1>
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using an id instead of a class, that's why only the first button works. Change it to class instead, then it should work. Try this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".request-btn").click(function(){
         var reference = this;
             $.ajax({
               url: "{% URL 'contact_details' %}" ,
               type: "GET",
               dataType:"json",
               success: 
         function(result){

          $.each(result, function() {
              html = "Email:" +this.email + "<br>" +"Mobile:" + this.mobile +"<hr>"
         $("#response").append(html)
        });
    }
});
});
}); 


</script>
```

I'm not sure what your second question is - could you please rephrase it or add details?

Comment: I changed the code as you said, but now I faced another problem. When I click one button all are working at the same time.

Comment: hi, MeL I tried this method, upon using this facing  problem is when I hit any button the output only shows in the first item